# show grocery crud using tab panel

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm newbie for grocery crud. I'm having a database table lets say customer_details, it includes customer_name & customer_id etc columns. I'm having another table called purches_details, customer_id is the foriegn key for this table.

I want to create a tab panel (menu) in my view  according to the customer_name column in customer_detail table. tabs names should be customer names

& when some one click the relevent customer_name tab the the relevent purches  details should show as the grocery crud grid.

Please help me friends, I want it so deeply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got this answer  ...

```
the controller from grocery CRUD 1.2.3 with CodeIgniter 2.1.2 (! try to use CI 2.1.2 or CI 2.1.0 versions + latest grocery CRUD):


            <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');    
        class Examples extends CI_Controller {    public function __construct()
            {
              parent::__construct();
              $this->load->database();
              $this->load->helper('url');
              $this->load->library('grocery_crud');
            }    
        public function _example_output($output = null)
            {
              $this->load->view('example', $output);
            }    public function index()
            {
              $this->_example_output( (object) array('output' => '', 'js_files' => array(), 'css_files' => array()));
            }    
        public function customers()
            {
              $crud = new grocery_crud();
              $crud->set_table('customer_details');
              $crud->set_subject('Customer Details');
              $output = $crud->render();
              $output->menu = $this->db->select('customer_id, customer_name')->get('customer_details')->result();
              $this->_example_output($output);
            }    public function purches_details($customer)
            {
              $company = $this->uri->segment(3);
              $crud = new grocery_crud();
              $crud->set_table('purches_details');
              $crud->set_subject('Purches Details');
              $crud->where('customer_id', $customer);
              $output = $crud->render();
              $output->menu = $this->db->select('customer_id, customer_name')->get('customer_details')->result();
              $this->_example_output($output);
            }    
        }

and the view with our customer names links:

            [CODE]
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <?php
            foreach($css_files as $file): ?>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $file; ?>" />
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php foreach($js_files as $file): ?>
            <script src="<?php echo $file; ?>"></script>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <style type='text/css'>
            body
            {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 14px;
            }
            a {
                color: blue;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            a:hover
            {
            text-decoration: underline;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div>
            <?php echo anchor('examples/customers', 'All Customers');?> :
            <?php foreach ($menu as $link) {?>
              <?php echo anchor("examples/purches_details/$link->customer_id", "$link->customer_name");?> &middot;
            <?php }?>
            </div>
            <div style='height:20px;'></div>
                <div>
              <?php echo $output; ?>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```